# How to split string by 'newline'?

Tags: android, string, split

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String str
while ((str =in.readLine()) != null)
{
     items = str.split("\n");
}
in.close();
```

String (str) contains data from a text file like:

January

February

March

etc.

Each word is on ag new line.
I want to read the string and separate each word on a new line and store into an array of String objects (this would be the variable named 'items').

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, `BufferedReader.readLine` *already* splits the input based on newlines.

So, where you currently have:

```
items=str.split("\n");
```

you only need to append `str` to your array.

For example, with the `infile` file holding:

```
January
February
March
April
May
June
```

the following program outputs `6` (the size of the array list created):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> itms = new ArrayList<String> ();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("infile"));
            String str;
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)
                itms.add(str);
            br.close();
            System.out.println (itms.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println ("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `readLine` method already reads line-by-line. There will be no `\n` characters in this string.

Try this instead:

```
ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    itemList.add(str);
}
in.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

this my code and its work for me

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content, "iso-8859-1"));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String s = null;

                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

                    itemList.add(s);


                }

                response = itemList.get(0);
                content.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
    }
}

public void readWebpage(View view) {
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.yourURL.com" });

}
```

**readWebpage** function is **onclick function** I create in my **button xml** like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/readWebpage" android:onClick="readWebpage" android:text="Load Webpage"></Button>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="Example Text"></TextView>
```

in my code I try to get the **first line** so I use **itemList.get(0)** if you want to get another line just change **the index** like **itemList.get(1)** or **itemList.get(n)**

Answer (score 0):

use `Arraylist` for this..

```
ArrayList<String> items= new ArrayList<String>();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String str;
while ((str =in.readLine()) != null)
{
    items.add(str.split("\n"));
}
in.close();
```

=====>Checking

```
 for(int i=0;i<items.size;i++)
 {
    System.out.println("item name "+items.get(i));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to split string by newline

I came to this question just wanting to split a string, not a file. So I will answer that here for future visitors.

Given

```
String myString = "one/ntwo/nthree";
```

You can convert it into an array with

```
String myArray[] = myString.split("\n");    // {"one", "two", "three"};
```

And if needed, that can be converted into a `List` with

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
Collections.addAll(myList, myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android/Java this is very simple. Follow this :-

Suppose

```
String txt="I am Rahul Kushwaha.I am an Android Developer";
```

Now, To split this into line by line.use **split()** method .Like:-

```
String txt_split=txt.split("\n");
System.out.println(txt_split);
```

OutPut :-

```
I
am
Rahul
Kushwaha
.
I
am
an
Android
Developer
```

Now, To get Length of Splited String use **lenght()** method.

```
int txt_length=txt_split.length();
System.out.println("text length=",txt_length);
```

Output:-

```
text length=10
```

To particular data by line .Do like this :-

```
String[] text_data=txt.split("\n");

System.out.println("Name :",text_data[2]);
System.out.println("Title :",text_data[3]);
System.out.println("Job :",text_data[8]);
```

OutPut:-

```
Name :Rahul
Title :Kushwaha
Job :Android
```

Hope this will help you.Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep blank lines if at all then you can use

```
String lines[] = givenString.split("\\r?\\n", -1);
```